# Finding WW2 records of a Luftwaffe pilot named Adolf Schwartz

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I’m trying to find records on my grandfather, his name was Adolf Schwartz and he was a Luftwaffe pilot in world war 2. I only have a picture of him.

Does anyone know where I could find his records?

He was born is 1913 in Rostock, Germany.

[image: Adolf Schwartz]

Comment: Are you looking specifically just for his military records or are you also looking for vital records like his birth certificate, marriage record, etc?

Comment: Mostly military I would love to know what rank he was and just general information